# Can't hit NuGet server hosted on an Azure website from Visual Studio, but can from web

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-server

My problem is that I have a NuGet server on an Azure website using Azure AD for auth.  It works as expected if I hit the NuGet URL in Chrome (requires the login, which accepts appropriate credentials), but if I try to access it in Visual Studio 2013 (through manage NuGet packages) it won't accept the account/password as appropriate credentials (the prompt just pops up again).  My approach was as follows:

With the goal of creating a simple internal NuGet server, I largely followed the instructions in this article to deploy one on an Azure website: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872230/Create-Your-Own-Private-NuGet-Server-in-Windows-Az

The NuGet server works just fine, but I wanted to add some basic auth since we'll be hosting some of our code there.  I decided to try to use Azure AD for this.  I added a couple Microsoft accounts (mine and a coworker's) to our otherwise empty default Azure active directory.  Through the management portal, I then selected the 'configure' tab in the website dashboard and added the default directory in the auth section.

Since the developers who will be pulling down our packages will do so through Visual Studio, I need to figure this out or find an alternative.  I would like (if possible) to avoid writing my own auth module, since this feature is supposed to be baked into Azure.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that NuGet does not currently support Azure AD.  However, they are working on it and progress can be tracked here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/708